# Overwrite declared jquery variable in linked file

Tags: jquery

I have a linked .js file that declares:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imagesTotal = 4;
}
```

Now I want to overwrite this inline within a HTML file. I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.imagesTotal = 4;
    }
```

and I've also tried declaring them both as

```
  window.imagesTotal = 4;
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "linked" .js file declares `imagesTotal` inside a function. Variables declared inside a function cannot be accessed outside of that function.

You'll have to somehow remove `var` before imagesTotal to make it global, or remove `var` and prepend `window.` to `imagesTotal` in your "linked" .js file.